# How do I query all posts associated with a custom taxonomy and then output those pages titles?

Tags: php, wordpress

The below only outputs the last posts title.. I need all of the titles associated with this taxonomy.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'apartment',
'tax_query' => array(
      array(
            'taxonomy' => 'mytax',
            'operator' => 'EXISTS'
      ),
),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$map = get_field('image_map_coordinates');
$title = get_the_title();

echo $title;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have to loop through the output to get each post title.

To make things reusable, I've created this function which returns all posts associated with a certain (custom) taxonomy:

```
/**
 * Returns a WP_Query object containing
 * all posts that are assigned to a specific
 * (custom) taxonomy.
 *
 * @param string $taxonomy The taxonomy the posts must be assigned to
 *
 * @return \WP_Query
 */
function get_posts_by_taxonomy(string $taxonomy): WP_Query {
    $query = [
        "post_type" => "post",
        "showposts" => -1,
        "tax_query" => [
            [
                "taxonomy" => esc_sql($taxonomy),
                "operator" => "EXISTS"
            ],
        ],
    ];

    return new WP_Query($query);
}
```

Note the `"showposts" => -1`; this is so we really get **all** posts.

Now that we've got the posts, let's loop through them and print the title of each of them:

```
/** $post stores all posts that are assigned to any category */
$posts = get_posts_by_taxonomy("category");

/** Check if there are any posts */
if ($posts->have_posts()) {
    /** Start the classic loop */
    while ($posts->have_posts()) {
        /** Don't forget to establish the current post */
        $posts->the_post();

        /** Print the post title */
        echo "<h1>" . get_the_title() . "</h1>";
    }
}
```

This should work.

Alternatively, you can also use [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) and loop through them with [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Again, here the slightly different function which does not return a `WP_Query` object but an array containing the results:

```
/**
 * Returns an array containing
 * all posts that are assigned to a specific
 * (custom) taxonomy.
 *
 * @param string $taxonomy The taxonomy the posts must be assigned to
 *
 * @return array The found posts
 */
function get_posts_by_taxonomy(string $taxonomy): array {
    $query = [
        "post_type" => "post",
        "showposts" => -1,
        "tax_query" => [
            [
                "taxonomy" => esc_sql($taxonomy),
                "operator" => "EXISTS"
            ],
        ],
    ];

    return get_posts($query);
}
```

And the loop:

```
/** $post stores all posts that are assigned to any category */
$posts = get_posts_by_taxonomy("category");

/** Loop through each found post and... */
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    /** ...print its title */
    echo "<h1>" . $post->post_title . "</h1>";
}
```